# Chrome memory leak

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm testing a page just spamming clicks very often on their element, but the chrome memory utilization keeps increasing very fast, few minutes after chrome is using 1GB of ram.

Even if reload or close the testing page the use of the memory continues the same as before.

Is possible somehow free or release this memory?

I did a video to help understand it better:
https://youtu.be/m-vkUyRa2JA

```js
e1 = document.querySelector("#pane-side > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div._1C6Zl > div._1c_mC > div._3Tw1q > span > span")

e2 = document.querySelector("#pane-side > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div._1C6Zl > div._1c_mC > div._3Tw1q > span > span")

while (true) {
    triggerMouseEvent(e1,'mousedown');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5));
    triggerMouseEvent(e2,'mousedown');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5));
}

function triggerMouseEvent(el, etype) {
    //console.log(el)
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent(etype, true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

I also tested without JavaScript, I did a macro using python, to do the same action sending clicks to the page:
https://youtu.be/qtelaishMiw

And happens the same thing, memory keeps increasing very fast.

Tested on Linux, just changing chat like on video above:
[image]

Is not possible to release or clear this memory?